# Plot a matplotlib line with a given slope

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a scatter plot with X axis from `150-360` and y from `50-260`.

The slope of the linear fit line is -40 degrees

What I want is a I can draw another line at -45 degrees to act as a guide to show that the actual line is "close" to -45 degrees?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: well I plotted the scatter plot using matplotlib and numpy arrays. I used mat plot lib again to calculate the linear sq fit line as well.

Comment: Please post the actual code you've tried in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot([150,360],[260,50],'k-')
```

Should be simple enough to move it up or down if you need to

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of [v3.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/users/whats_new.html#new-axes-axline-method) you can plot a line with a given slope (passing through a given point) with `axline`:

```
intercept = ((360-150)/2, (260-50)/2)
ax.axline(intercept, slope=-45)
```